# Can I download Ubuntu 12.04 on a notebook/laptop?

Tags: 12.04, installation

I´ve had some problems with my Ubuntu instalation. 
  I considered reinstalling the OS completely, but the downloads for Ubuntu 12.04 I find online say they are desktop downloads. Can I use one of these downloads for my notebook, or is there a different download I should be looking for?

Comment: There is no difference. Desktop means environment. Ubuntu desktop or ubuntu server..

Comment: There is not enough information here for us to help you (i.e. need more specifics on why/how the updates failed etc.)

Comment: You need to know whether 32bit or 64bit, but desktop is fine for laptops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ubuntu-desktop runs on netbooks and laptops. If you are concerned about the performance of your laptop running the desktop version of Ubuntu you should try [Lubuntu](http://lubuntu.net/) which is a lightweight distro based on Ubuntu but using the [LXDE desktop environment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LXDE). [Lubuntu 12.10](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/lubuntu/releases/12.10/release/) is the latest version.

Comment: I apologize for such a late response as I just received the information in your post. I wasn't using Ubuntu for a few years but now I am and I appreciate any and every post that helps me learn it. Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

it is as web-e said:

there is an ubuntu-desktop dvd just to differentiate from the ubuntu-server dvd

I run ubuntu-desktop on my netbook just fine